# node.js readline - write data appears in input

Tags: node.js, readline

I've got a very basic readline implementation which seems to have a problem that when I write the written data appears in input and raises a 'line' event.  This is all in a standard linux rxvt window.

```
var rl  readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
//    terminal: false   <--- setting true/false makes no difference
});

rl.on('line', function(line) {
    var inp = line.trim();
    console.log('line event');
    switch(inp) {
        case   ....
    default:
       console.log('Unknown command: ' + inp + '\n');
    }
});
```

And then 
    rl.write(string);

from socket i/o.  The write raises 'line' event and the written data apears as an unknown command.

If I enter data on terminal it raises 'line' event as expected and works OK.

Clearly data written shouldn't appear on input and asking what might be the reason for this.

Thanks

Comment: what is your node version ?

Answer (score 4):

Actually `rl.write` will trigger line event. It should be in the docs but it isn't. If you want to bypass the parser simply write to process.stdout.

Previously `terminal: false` would cause output to have a trailing endline, forcing line event trigger. So you could give it true to avoid that, but now it has been changed so changing option won't help.

See the raised [issue](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/4243). Last comment says the same.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I'm intrigued by 'by design'.  Seems barking mad to me.

Comment: Glad that it helped. Had to waste hours on this myself.